# Is it not uncommon to omit "have" or "has" of present perfect sentences in informal conversations?

Tags: present-perfect

When reading online articles, I often come across sentences like "I never seen . . .", which apparently looks either "have" or "'ve" is omitted after "I".

Here are some examples.

> [Yahoo News](https://www.yahoo.com/news/grizzly-bear-takes-down-bull-082533704.html)
>  Krisztina Gayler, who recorded this footage,
> described it as "unbelievable" to witness. "**I never seen** anything
> like this in person," she wrote on Facebook.

> [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/jun/04/george-floyd-memorial-minneapolis)
>  "Held the bible in his hand. I've been
> preaching since I was a little boy. **I never seen** anyone hold a
> bible like that," Sharpton quipped.

> [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2002/05/28/books/writers-in-place-suffering-and-creativity.html)
>  "**I been** here all my life and **I
> never seen** it so bad," Clarence Blunt, Ms. Blunt's father, said at
> supper on Saturday night in Malta.

Is it common for native speakers to omit "have", "has", "'ve" or "'s" from present perfect sentences in informal conversations?

Comment: It’s common in certain dialects but definitely non-standard.

Comment: When I hear "I seen" and "I done" in the UK, they are mostly used as simple pasts rather than abbreviated perfects, but they do read more as abbreviated perfects in TeeBee's examples.  It may be different in different dialects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As StephenS observed, usages such as "I been", "I seen" are dialectal and definitely not part of standard English.